# Increasing characters in a string by a particular value

Tags: java, string

Let's say I want to take a string and increase each character (including spaces) by +n and then print out that new string. For instance:

> string 1 = 'look out'
>
> n = 7
>
> So string 2 would = 'svvrgvba'

Does that make sense? Anyway, I'm not sure how to get off the ground here. Do I need to split the original string up into its constituent characters before I increase their value by `n`? Or can I just use something like `string.charAt(0) + n`?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is define what happens at "z" + 1.

Comment: I've re-tagged  your question as `C#`, assuming that's what "CS" means. Feel free to correct if I'm wrong but please don't forget to tag your questions correctly. This site covers all programming languages and technology.

Comment: Huh... "CS" is "Computer Science", isn't it?

Comment: CS = computer science. Java student actually. :-)

Comment: You haven't answered for @deceze's question yet

Comment: z + 7 would wrap around. So if z = 27 (since space = 1), and 27 + 7 = 34. Then 34 % 27 = 7, which is 'f'.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s1="look out";
int n=7;
char[] c= s1.toCharArray();
String f="";
for(int i=0 ; i<s1.length() ; i++) {
    if(c[i]==' ' || c[i]=='z'){
        c[i]= 'a';
    for(int j=1 ; j<n; j++){
c[i]++;
}

}
else{
     for(int j=0 ; j<n; j++){
    c[i]++;
    if(c[i]=='z'){

    c[i]= 'a';
    c[i]--;

}
}
}

f += c[i];
}
SOP(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
l → 108  Adding 7 will result in 115 decimal value, which is the char s
o → 111  Adding 7 will result in 117 decimal value, which is the char v
o → 111  ..
k → 107  ..
  → 32   ..
o → 111  ..
u → 117  Adding 7 will result in 124, but you exceed 122 (z) by 2, so you convert it to b
t → 116  ..
```

You'll get `svvrgvba` if you add `7` to each char. But you should take care of cases like when adding `7` to `t` (You actually get one decimal value after `z`, and in that case you should switch it to `a`).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, but what if n = 10000 or something?

Comment: You could use n % 26 to find how much to increment each letter.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "ROT7", [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) is the wikipedia article for ROT13

Answer (score 0):

Caesar coding uses this.

You can indeed just look at each character seperatly and loop through them, adding the values to each character just like Maroun told you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
int n = 7;
n = n%26; //This will solve your problem if n is a large number like 1000
String str = "look out";
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
int ascii = 0; 
int newAscii = 0;
String newStr ="";
char c;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  ascii = arr[i];
  if(ascii == 32)
    newAscii = 97+n-1;
  else if((ascii+n)>122)
    newAscii = 97+(n-1-(122-ascii));
  else
    newAscii = ascii+7;
  c = (char)newAscii;
  newStr += c;
}
System.out.println(newStr);
```

If you think of using capital letters in between also then use this `else if` condition as well.

```
else if(ascii<=90)
    {
        if((ascii+n)>90) 
          newAscii = 65+(n-1-(90-ascii));
        else
          newAscii = ascii+n;
    }
```